# How to integrate Angular in Spring Boot using Gradle?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have a problem to combine Spring Boot + Angular + Gradle and fire up the applications to work together.

I created an empty folder named `my-app` in it I created a new spring boot project that is a folder named `backend`, I placed the Angular project in the folder `backend/src/resources/webapp/frontend`.

So in a nutshell it looks like this:

```
my-app 
 --backend (Spring)
   --src
     --resources
       --webapp
        --frontend (Angular)
```

In the main runtime file `BackendApplication.java`
I placed a simple endpoint with a **hello world** message to verify that the backend application is created (still without the Angular folder created) at `localhost:8080`, the application launched and displayed the message. After initializing the Angular CLI project, going to `localhost:4200`, I get the welcome page from Angular, so everything works.

However, how can I combine, the two projects?
I run two terminals one with the spring application going to the folder where spring is I run the command ./gradlew bootRun the application builds to 80% with the message **EXECUTING**, (displays a message from endpoint) and Angular application I run the ng serve command and can normally go to `localhost:4200`

The problem is that I don't know if the apps work together or if I just ran 2 separate projects that do two different things. How should such applications be built, it seems to me that it should only work under one address and not two.

I don't know how I could combine this to make the applications "**talk to each other**".
I'll add that I haven't configured anything in the `gradle` files, maybe I should configure something there?

This is my first attempt to connect backend and frontend and I don't know how to do it sensibly

Comment: You can run `ng build` in the angular project folder and copy the resulting files in the dist folder to the static folder of you spring project. (You can automate this process by changing `outputPath` in `angular.json`.) This would mean the applications would run in the same container if you containerize your spring application. You could also deploy the angular application to an nginx container and either allow the origin of the angular application in your spring project or add some configuration to the containers, and in the angular project using the `--proxy-config` flag to run it locally.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 Hey, thanks for the reply, I used the first way, that is, I copy the files from the dist folder to the static folder in the spring, I automated the process by changing the `outputPath `. However, I have a question how can I containerize the spring application so that the applications can run in the same container?

Comment: Simplest way is to just use maven to build an image. It is good practice to use the maven wrapper, so everyone uses the same version of maven: `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image`. Make sure docker runs. If you don't have a wrapper you can generate it with `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper`. Or you can just use your locally installed version of maven if it is a personal project. After that you can create a container from the image with docker. [Here](https://github.com/H3AR7B3A7/DockerAndKubernetes/blob/master/Spring.md) you can find some more documentation in one of my old repos if it helps.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 Acctually in my project I use `gradle`, but probably there will be no problem to generate an image and create a container. I mean we are using docker. Ok, so if I understand correctly, after building the container. I run the "whole application (spring + angular)" using the command `docker run` + port name, and then the applications talk to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Single Container

You can run `ng build` in the angular project folder and copy the resulting files in the dist folder to the static folder of you spring project. (You can automate this process by changing `outputPath` in `angular.json`.) This would mean the applications would run in the same container if you containerize your spring application.

Then just build an image:
`./mvnw spring-boot:build-image`

*Note: You could also use a `Dockerfile`. This can help with consistency if deployment gets more complex. Using docker compose makes the command really simple, and it wouldn't change even if you wanted to change project management for some reason. Which is nice for automation.*

And run a container:
`docker run yourImage:version`

For more info on using `Gradle` instead of `Maven`, or `Docker` in general you can explore this older repo of mine:

- [Spring + Maven / Gradle](https://github.com/H3AR7B3A7/DockerAndKubernetes/blob/master/Spring.md)
- [Docker](https://github.com/H3AR7B3A7/DockerAndKubernetes/blob/master/Docker.md)

### Two Containers

You could also deploy the angular application to an `nginx` container and either allow the origin of the angular application in your spring project or add some configuration to the containers, and in the angular project using the `--proxy-config` flag to run it locally

This can be a little more work, but is the better practice. However, I recommend to create some `Spring Boot Actuator /health endpoint` so the angular app can handle your back end not being healthy / online.