# How do I execute a docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I created the images locally and created one repository in **DockerHub** called `testName/backend`.

The `docker images` command shows the created images.

```
 REPOSITORY              TAG              IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE  
    testName/backend       0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   10fc47e065ff   25 minutes ago   459MB 
    backend                 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   10fc47e065ff   25 minutes ago   459MB 
    backend                 latest           2f5cc7be2b5d   41 minutes ago   479MB 
    alpine/git              latest           22a2874e1112   3 weeks ago      39.5MB
    hello-world             latest           feb5d9fea6a5   10 months ago    13.3kB
```

And I would like to run the container with a command in the format `docker run yourImage:version`. So according to this (so I think I should call such a command: `docker run 10fc47e065ff:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
However, I get this message: **Unable to find image '10fc47e065ff:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' locally
docker: error response from daemon: pull access denied for 10fc47e065ff, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.**

I will add that I am logged in.

What am I doing wrong that I can't get the container to work?

By the way, I have a question about the docker in the context of the application. Generally, in this image there is a Spring Boot + Angular application. I am uploading it to a container, and spring + angular is supposed to work together with each other . And generally the question I have is whether I will have to create a new image every time I make a modification to the application code, or if I run the application using the `docker run` command then the image will be automatically overwritten and every time I run the application I will get the "latest version" of the application.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} backend.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.34.0"
    id "com.palantir.docker-run" version "0.34.0"

}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

docker {
    name "${project.name}:${project.version}"
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*", "backend.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "backend.jar"])
    files 'backend.jar'
    tag 'DockerHub', "testName/backend:${project.version}"
}

dockerRun {
    name "${project.name}"
    image "${project.name}:${project.version}"
    ports '8081:8081'
    clean true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct image name. The image ID (`10fc47e065ff`) is a unique identifier so you could use that and not need to refer to a tag at all, or else you use the image name (repository as shown in the list) in combination with the tag to reference a unique image. eg. `testName/backend:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

If you application code changes, you will need to build a new image. So if you needed to rebuild the spring boot application you would also rebuild the image - this would produce a new image with a new ImageID. The ImageID is unique to each image build, but you can name/rename and label/relabel any image anytime. The ImageID is a unique identifier but the name/tag combination is not. Typically you might use the image label `latest` to always get the most recently build image. Alternatively, if you want to know exactly what image you want to deploy/run you would use a specific image name and tag that you have assigned to the image.

Comment: Heck, it's kind of weak that I have to build a new image every time. Generally, I wanted to make a container so that Spring and Angular together "talk" communicate, but frankly, I don't see much of a need to build a new image and go through the process after every change (although I understand the necessity and sense as much as possible), but I would like to have a live preview while building the application - possibly after restarting the application. Alternatively, how, to do local communication of spring with angular?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: You development cycle is up to you. For me, if I was developing a set of spring and angular apps I'd be running both locally in my IDE as I developed, until I had a stable build to move onto the next step on integration testing. At that stage I might test with just the self-packaged applications or I might create the images then and test those against each other. Ideally you use something like a CI/CD tool to do the image building automatically as required and deploy to test/stage/production environments, etc. There are many ways to do things so make it work for you now, then improve/advance..

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Actually, all I want is that, I don't know if I can call it that, Spring and Angular, go on the same port - they can communicate with each other (locally for now). Because, spring goes on port `http://localhost:8080/` and angular `http://localhost:4200/` apps work as I run them on their ports just wish they could communicate with each other. 

Maybe at a later stage docker will come in handy, but for now I would like to run this locally only.

Comment: Why did I even start mentioning docker? I was brought by this thread :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73353008/how-to-integrate-angular-in-spring-boot-using-gradle/73354906#73354906

Comment: You cannot have 2 apps on the same port on the same server (or docker container). I presume your front-end angular app is communicating to the back-end spring app? So locally, your Angular would run on 4200 and that is the port you access the web app on and it talks to the local spring app on 8080. In docker you have an image/container for each. The apps run on whatever port internally and you can expose (map) that internal port of 8080 outside the container. You could run spring + angular in the same container, but you would then only need to expose the angular app outside the container.

Comment: So in summary, in two separate terminals I run applications (spring and angular). In spring I define e.g. endpoints (GET,POST etc) and refer to them in angular, and my "main" application i.e. backend + frontend is on port `localhost:4200` (on Angular side). If this is the case, then I close, the thread. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Basically, yeah that's how you can set this up locally. Please accept one of the answers that best answers your original question - we have slightly deviated off topic in these comments!

Answer (score 0):

try use `docker run -d backend: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 0):

It should helps you:

```
docker run -d testName/backend:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

As for your second question... Yes, you have to rebuild the image every time you change the code. If you run `docker build` and an image with the same repository name and tag already locally exists, then the name and tag of the previous image will be set to `<none>`.

It looks like you should modify your Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} backend.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "backend.jar"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure that you have to use the Image ID. Do `docker -ps -a` and try with `docker run [container_id]`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).